# How to Get the BaseURL from axios.create({baseURL})?

Tags: javascript, networking, axios

I'm trying to get the baseURL from `customApi.js` axios that is created using `export default axios.create()`configuration.

customApi.js file

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://123.123.123.123:5000'
});
```

I tried the following, but it console logs `undefined`.

```
import api from 'customApi.js';

console.log(api.baseURL);
```

What is the correct way to get the base url in a custom configured axios?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is how I found it.

```js
const x = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://123.123.123.123:5000'
});

// for (let o in x) console.log(o,x[o])

console.log(x.defaults.baseURL)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.2/axios.min.js"></script>
```